# Kivy (Python) TabbedPanel - different (dynamic) sized tabs?

Tags: python, tabs, kivy, kivy-language

Kivy seems to want to make all tabs the same size.
What if I want to make one tab wider than others?  Adjusting tab_width for a TabbedPanelItem seems to have no effect, and as such the longer text is getting cut off.

Example modified slightly from [Kivy TabbedPanel docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.tabbedpanel.html), where I changed the first tab's heading to "Long Text for a Tab":

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""

<Test>:
    #size_hint: .5, .5
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Long Text for a Tab'
        tab_width: self.texture_size[0]
        Label:
            text: 'First tab content area'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'tab2'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'Second tab content area'
            Button:
                text: 'Button that does nothing'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'tab3'
        RstDocument:
            text:
                '\\n'.join(("Hello world", "-----------",
                "You are in the third tab."))

""")


class Test(TabbedPanel):
    pass


class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

...so the "Long Text" gets chopped up because all 3 tabs get the same width.  Even setting the first tab's tab_width to a constant (e.g. 300) gets ignored.

Seems that you can supply tab_width to the TabbedPanel and it makes all tabs the same, but how do you make individual tabs (TabbedPanelItems) to have different (even dynamic) widths, i.e. so that some tabs are wider than others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tab_width` is a `TabbedPanel` property, not a `TabbedPanelItem` property and is applied to all tabs.

To set a different size to each tab you can set `tab_widht` to `None` and then use `TabbedPanelItem` properties properly (it is based on `Togglebutton`, so you can use `size_hint_x` and `size` properties):

```
<Test>:
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    do_default_tab: False
    tab_width: None

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Long Text for a Tab'
        size_hint_x: None
        width: self.texture_size[0]
        padding: 10, 0

        Label:
            text: 'First tab content area'
```

**Edit:**

Apparently it is necessary to explicitly update the width of the tabs  after the initialization of `TabbedPanel`, you can use `Clock.schedule`_once and `on_tab_width` method to do this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel, TabbedPanelItem
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""

<CustomWidthTabb@TabbedPanelItem>
    width: self.texture_size[0]
    padding: 10, 0
    size_hint_x: None

<Test>:
    size_hint: 1,1
    do_default_tab: False
    tab_width: None

    CustomWidthTabb:
        text: "This is a Long Tab"
        Label:
            text: 'First tab content area'

    CustomWidthTabb:
        text: "This is a Long Tab"
        Label:
            text: 'Second tab content area'

    CustomWidthTabb:
        text: "Short Tab"     
        Label:
            text: 'Third tab content area'

    CustomWidthTabb:
        text: "Short Tab#2"   
        Label:
            text: 'Fourth tab content area'

""")



class Test(TabbedPanel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.on_tab_width, 0.1)

class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's very close to correct! ...and yet an artifact of that particular choice of 3 tabs. :( Try adding more tabs or making the names longer, and you may see what I just got when I tried your suggestion: Copying those similar settings for each of 4 tabs ("This is a Long Tab", "This is Another Long Tab", "Short Tab", "Short Tab#2"), the later tabs get "scrunched" such that all tabs are squeezed into the left 50% of the screen (with unused black toward the right, and the tab-texts running into each other & even getting cut off).  Making the window bigger doesn't help.

Comment: @sh37211 You're right, look at the edition. I do not know if it's the best option. Regrettably, I do not have the time to  investigate this now, so it is posible that I may be missing something ...