# Python Kivy TabbedPanel - setting custom tab widths

Tags: python, tabs, kivy, kivy-language

Thanks for years of unknowingly helping me!! I've used this site so much but this is the first time that I'm actually going to have to post a question to get the info I need, which is amazing.

I've recently started learning Python (& Kivy) so I'm still a beginner. 
I'm using:

```
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
```

I'm trying to resize the tabs(TabbedPanelItem) in a TabbedPanel so that they have adequate horizontal size, to allow for the text.
There's another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48717727/kivy-python-tabbedpanel-different-dynamic-sized-tabs) which has been answered with a solution.
I've found this solution to work for me too, but only provided that I don't use a screen and put the Tabbed Panel inside anything else.

As soon as I change the structure so that the Tabbed Panel is nested, the solution no longer works.

Here is some example code which I took from the solution but modified it so that the Tabbed Panel isn't the root:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel, TabbedPanelItem
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""

<Test2>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        GridLayout:
            rows:1
            Label:
                text:'Does it show all 4 tabs?'
        GridLayout:
            rows:1
            TestForTabbedPanel

<CustomWidthTabb@TabbedPanelItem>
    width: self.texture_size[0]
    padding: 10, 0
    size_hint_x: None

<TestForTabbedPanel>:
    size_hint: 1,1
    do_default_tab: False
    tab_width: None

    CustomWidthTabb:
        text: "This is a Long Tab"
        Label:
            text: 'First tab content area'

    CustomWidthTabb:
        text: "This is a Long Tab"
        Label:
            text: 'Second tab content area'

    CustomWidthTabb:
        text: "Short Tab"     
        Label:
            text: 'Third tab content area'

    CustomWidthTabb:
        text: "Short Tab#2"   
        Label:
            text: 'Fourth tab content area'

""")

class Test2(Screen):
    pass

class TestForTabbedPanel(TabbedPanel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestForTabbedPanel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.on_tab_width, 0.1)

class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test2()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

[image: ResultExampleImage]

Compared to this, the solution provided in the other thread without nesting the tabbed panel works; it shows all the tabs and they have been sized dynamically:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel, TabbedPanelItem
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""

<CustomWidthTabb@TabbedPanelItem>
    width: self.texture_size[0]
    padding: 10, 0
    size_hint_x: None

<Test>:
    size_hint: 1,1
    do_default_tab: False
    tab_width: None

    CustomWidthTabb:
        text: "This is a Long Tab"
        Label:
            text: 'First tab content area'

    CustomWidthTabb:
        text: "This is a Long Tab"
        Label:
            text: 'Second tab content area'

    CustomWidthTabb:
        text: "Short Tab"     
        Label:
            text: 'Third tab content area'

    CustomWidthTabb:
        text: "Short Tab#2"   
        Label:
            text: 'Fourth tab content area'

""")



class Test(TabbedPanel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.on_tab_width, 0.1)

class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

How can I write the code, so that the TabbedPanel is nested inside a screen or another widget, but shows all the tabs with their adequate widths?
What basics am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Please refer to the example for details.

### kv file

Add `id` for `TestForTabbedPanel:`

```
    GridLayout:
        rows:1
        TestForTabbedPanel:
            id: tp
```

### Python code

1. Move the `__init__()` method from class *TestForTabbedPanel* to class *Test2*
2. Replace `super(TestForTabbedPanel, self)` with `super(Test2, self)`
3. Replace `self.on_tab_width` with `self.ids.tp.on_tab_width`
4. Add `pass` to class *TestForTabbedPanel

```
class Test2(Screen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Test2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.ids.tp.on_tab_width, 0.1)


class TestForTabbedPanel(TabbedPanel):
    pass
```

## Example

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel, TabbedPanelItem
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""

<Test2>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        GridLayout:
            rows:1
            Label:
                text:'Does it show all 4 tabs?'
        GridLayout:
            rows:1
            TestForTabbedPanel:
                id: tp

<CustomWidthTabb@TabbedPanelItem>
    width: self.texture_size[0]
    padding: 10, 0
    size_hint_x: None

<TestForTabbedPanel>:
    size_hint: 1,1
    do_default_tab: False
    tab_width: None

    CustomWidthTabb:
        text: "This is a Long Tab"
        Label:
            text: 'First tab content area'

    CustomWidthTabb:
        text: "This is a Long Tab"
        Label:
            text: 'Second tab content area'

    CustomWidthTabb:
        text: "Short Tab"     
        Label:
            text: 'Third tab content area'

    CustomWidthTabb:
        text: "Short Tab#2"   
        Label:
            text: 'Fourth tab content area'

""")


class Test2(Screen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Test2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.ids.tp.on_tab_width, 0.1)


class TestForTabbedPanel(TabbedPanel):
    pass


class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test2()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - All tabs displayed]

Comment: Works perfectly, much appreciated.

Comment: Please remember to mark the question as answered by *Clicking the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer".*